# How to run OWASP ZAP automatically using command line operations (i.e. Jenkins)

Tags: zap

I am trying to run OWASP ZAP automatically using command line. I have tried using the API as described [here](https://www.securify.nl/blog/SFY20150303/automating-security-tests-using-owasp-zap-and-jenkins.html), but I am getting [these errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566018/getting-error-in-python-code-for-automate-owsap-zap-for-the-application).

I have also tried with [zapr](https://github.com/garethr/zapr), but it's also showing error as set path while I have try to set it by every possible combination.

You have any way and their steps/tutorial (link, video) so I can achieve same.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566018/getting-error-in-python-code-for-automate-owsap-zap-for-the-application/45588479?noredirect=1#comment78136492_45588479 no point in duplicating it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue while trying it. Not sure if you found a way to set the ZAP home path for the zapr wrapper. This worked for me:

```
zapr --summary --debug --zap-path $/usr/share/zaproxy/zap.sh http://localhost:3000
```